# Compare user input against elements in array disregarding white spaces

Tags: ruby, string

I want to compare a user input `player` with the elements in an array `players`:

```
players = ["KYRIE IRVING", "KEVIN DURANT", "KAWHI LEONARD"]
```

If `player` is in `players` disregarding spaces in `player`, then I want to move forward; otherwise, I want it to display an error message. For example, if `player` is `"KYRIE IRVING"`, `"Kyrie Irving"`, `"kyrie irving"`, or `"kyrieirving"`, I want to move forward.

The following code doesn't work with `"kyrieirving"`.

```
def valid_player(player, fan, players, vote_history)
  until players.include?(player) || **players.gsub(/\s+/, "").include?(player)**
    puts "\n   Oops! That's not a valid player. Please try again."  
    print "\n   Fan #{fan}: "  
    player = gets.chomp.upcase 
  end 
 vote_history << player
end
```

I could create another array that has all the elements of players without the spaces, then compare with that. I also could create a block in which the `gsub` method applies to each element of the array. I'm assuming there's a cleaner solution than either of these two options though.

Comment: Please edit your question so the code is properly formatted. Its not readable as is.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited.

Comment: What's up with the trailing dots?

Comment: Your method seems rather busy.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why do you think "creat[ing] another array that has all the elements of players without the spaces, then compare with that" not a clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

The following will match kyrieirving:

```
re = /KYRIE IRVING/mix
```

The follwoing will match  KYRIE IRVING, Kyrie Irving, kyrie irving :

```
re = /KYRIE IRVING/mi
```

x stands for ignore whitespace... you may prepare two regex one with x flag and another without and apply both while iterating through your array. Otherwise you will have to apply things (which I think would have been better) that you have mentioned in your post as FORBIDDEN :)

```
re = /KYRIE IRVING/mi
str = 'KYRIE IRVING, Kyrie Irving, kyrie irving, or kyrieirving,'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A few points

- puts in ruby includes a newline so you don't need to begin your strings with newline if you call puts.
- I find its easier to store everything in lower case, not upper case. Much easier to read.
- I would use recursion to check for a valid response, not a loop.

something like this:

```
def valid_player(fan, players, vote_history)
    player = gets.strip
    player_no_spc = player.gsub(" ","").downcase
    players_no_spc = players.map{ |s| s.gsub(" ","")}

    if players_no_spc.include?(player_no_spc)
       return vote_history << player
    else
       puts "Oops! That's not a valid player. Please try again."
       puts "Fan #{fan}: "
       valid_player(fan, players, vote_history)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I'm running this in terminal so using the newline in addition to puts to make it look better when it's actually run (granted this makes the code look worse).

The challenge I would have with players_no_spc is that I print the elements of the array elsewhere in the program and I want the spacing in those spots.

Comment: The code I gave you preserves the spacing in players, just uses the no spaces version for comparison. If you don't want to use regular expressions, this is probably the best solution. If you want something that takes up less screen space, go with the rizwan's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
players = %w|KYRIEIRVING KEVINDURANT KAWHILEONARD|
player_to_check = "Kyrie IRVING"
if p = players.detect? { |p| p == player_to_check.delete(' ').upcase }
  puts "Found: #{p}"
else
  puts "Oops!"
end
```

Comment: That means preprocessing the values in the array temporarily which the op mentioned as he doesn't want to do, although this approach is better none the less :)

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman I never understood the claim starting with “I don’t want to,” specifically when asking a question.

Comment: Thanks! I said I don't want to as I thought there was bound to be a better way (...this is the third program I've written so I'm verrry new). 

Nevertheless, doesn't sound like there's a great solution that avoids two arrays, but still lets me print with the spaces. Players can have additional elements based on what the user enters.

I will play around some more and see where I get.

Comment: @Brandy with the existing things you have you may play around the'x' option that i have mentioned along iwth 'i' - case insenstive option in my answer.. by using both you have to build two regex but a full regex solution without preprocessing anything...

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @TobySpeight please feel free to edit the answer to add anything you think it misses.